# Python / MySQL / Selenium - Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, web-scraping, mysql-connector

I believe there is an issue regarding the MySQL database as I have ran the code **without** the MySQL code and **Python/Selenium works fine**. When running the code the first iteration of the `for link in links:` is ran then breaks due to the following error message: **`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'followers' referenced before assignment`**

Can someone please advise where the error is? I have tried several solutions from similar topics with no success.

**Output:**

```
Barbecue Records
Australia
https://d1fuks2cnuq5t9.cloudfront.net/i/2uQiBiM7jpSCowBXEOqfZdu9x9FCcTf9u7iZygAg.jpg
Tech House
House
Nu Disco
Techno
Deep House
Soundcloud N/A
https://www.facebook.com/barbecuerecords
https://www.beatport.com/label/barbecue-records/33621
https://www.barbecuerecords.com/
info@barbecuerecords.com
demo@barbecuerecords.com
https://labelsbase.net/barbecue-records
File "/Users/tom/Desktop/WebScraping/label_scraper.py", line 122, in <module>
        scrapeLabels(country)
      File "/Users/tom/Desktop/WebScraping/label_scraper.py", line 118, in scrapeLabels
        values = (title, page, src, genre, soundcloud, followers, facebook, beatport, website, email, demo, link)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'followers' referenced before assignment
```

**DB Code:**

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root', 
    passwd='',
    database='Labels'
)

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE labels (
        title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        image BLOB,
        genre VARCHAR(30),
        sc_link VARCHAR(50),
        sc_followers SMALLINT,
        fb_link VARCHAR(50),
        bp_link VARCHAR(50),
        website VARCHAR(50),
        gen_email VARCHAR(50),
        demo_email VARCHAR(50),
        labelbase VARCHAR(50)
        )''')
```

**Python/Selenium Code -**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time
import string
import mysql.connector

PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
links = []

countries = ['Australia','United+Kingdom','United+States','Spain','Portugal','France','Germany','Italy','Ireland']

db = mysql.connector.connect(
host='localhost',
user='root', 
passwd='',
database='Labels')

mycursor = db.cursor()  

def extractHrefs():
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]')
            cards = body.find_elements_by_class_name('label-card-logo-link')
            for card in cards:
                links.append(card.get_attribute('href'))
            nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="›"]')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextpage)
        except:
            break

def scrapeLabels(page):
    url = 'https://labelsbase.net/?g=Techno%2C+Tech+House%2C+Deep+House%2C+House%2C+Progressive+House%2C+Electronica%2C+Breaks%2C+Downtempo&c={}'.format(page)
    driver.get(url)
    extractHrefs()
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(1)
        # -- Title
        try:
            title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('label-name').text
            print(title)
        except: 
            print('Title N/A')
        # -- Country
        page = str(page).replace('+',' ')
        print(page)
        # -- Image
        try:
            image = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
            src = image.get_attribute('src')
            print(src)
        except: 
            print('Image N/A')
        # -- Genres
        try:
            genres = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[title*='More']")
            for genre in genres:
                genre = genre.text
                print(genre)
        except:
            print('Genre N/A')
        # -- Soundcloud link & followers
        try: 
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-fw"]')
            soundcloud = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            followers = soundcloud.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::span').text
            print('Soundcloud Followers:',followers)
            print(soundcloud)
        except:
            print('Soundcloud N/A')
        # -- Facebook
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"]')
            facebook = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(facebook)
        except:
            print('Facebook N/A')
        # -- Beatport
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-fw"]')
            beatport = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(beatport)
        except:
            print('Beatport N/A')
        # -- Label Website
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-globe fa-fw"]')
            website = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(website)
        except:
            print('Label Website N/A')
        # -- Emails
        try:
            email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'@')]").text
            print(email)
            try:
                demo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'demo')]").text
                print(demo)
            except:
                pass
        except:
            print('Email N/A')
        # -- Labelbase Link
        print(link)

        sql = '''INSERT INTO labels (title, country, image, genre, sc_link, sc_followers, fb_link, bp_link, website, gen_email, demo_email, labelbase) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        values = (title, page, src, genre, soundcloud, followers, facebook, beatport, website, email, demo, link)
        mycursor.executemany(sql,values)

for country in countries:
    scrapeLabels(country)
    db.commit()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is:
Inside the `for link in links:` loop, inside the

```
try: 
    child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-fw"]')
    soundcloud = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
    followers = soundcloud.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::span').text
    print('Soundcloud Followers:',followers)
    print(soundcloud)
```

block, something goes wrong, so the exception is thrown and you do not reach the

```
followers = soundcloud.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::span').text
```

line, so the `followers` variable still not initialized.
But after that you are trying to use this variable in

```
values = (title, page, src, genre, soundcloud, followers, facebook, beatport, website, email, demo, link)
```

line, so Python doesn't recognize this variable since it still was not initialized ever.
**UPD**
To avoid such situations maybe the simples approach is to define all these variables at the beginning of the block / scope where they are used and initialize them to empty string.
Anyway, this is just a my suggestion. As following:

```
def scrapeLabels(page):
    url = 'https://labelsbase.net/?g=Techno%2C+Tech+House%2C+Deep+House%2C+House%2C+Progressive+House%2C+Electronica%2C+Breaks%2C+Downtempo&c={}'.format(page)
    driver.get(url)
    extractHrefs()
    for link in links:
        title = ""
        page = ""
        src = ""
        genre = ""
        soundcloud = ""
        followers = ""
        facebook = ""
        beatport = ""
        website = ""
        email = ""
        demo = ""
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(1)
        # -- Title
        try:
            title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('label-name').text
            print(title)
        except: 
            print('Title N/A')
        # -- Country
        page = str(page).replace('+',' ')
        print(page)
        # -- Image
        try:
            image = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
            src = image.get_attribute('src')
            print(src)
        except: 
            print('Image N/A')
        # -- Genres
        try:
            genres = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[title*='More']")
            for genre in genres:
                genre = genre.text
                print(genre)
        except:
            print('Genre N/A')
        # -- Soundcloud link & followers
        try: 
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-fw"]')
            soundcloud = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            followers = soundcloud.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::span').text
            print('Soundcloud Followers:',followers)
            print(soundcloud)
        except:
            print('Soundcloud N/A')
        # -- Facebook
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"]')
            facebook = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(facebook)
        except:
            print('Facebook N/A')
        # -- Beatport
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-fw"]')
            beatport = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(beatport)
        except:
            print('Beatport N/A')
        # -- Label Website
        try:
            child = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-globe fa-fw"]')
            website = child.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('href')
            print(website)
        except:
            print('Label Website N/A')
        # -- Emails
        try:
            email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'@')]").text
            print(email)
            try:
                demo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'demo')]").text
                print(demo)
            except:
                pass
        except:
            print('Email N/A')
        # -- Labelbase Link
        print(link)

        sql = '''INSERT INTO labels (title, country, image, genre, sc_link, sc_followers, fb_link, bp_link, website, gen_email, demo_email, labelbase) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        values = (title, page, src, genre, soundcloud, followers, facebook, beatport, website, email, demo, link)
        mycursor.executemany(sql,values)
```

Comment: I believe you are correct! What would be best practice when facing an error like this? Would defaulting all the variables to NULL then updating when selenium extracts data?

Comment: I would define all those variables at the beginning of the block / scope where they are used as empty string like `followers = ""` before or immediately after the `driver.get(url)` line

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you don't assign a value to your variable "followers" in your try/except clause?

Your line `values = (title, page, src, genre, soundcloud, followers, facebook, beatport, website, email, demo, link)` won't know what to do because there is no value for followers.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `followers` inside a `try/except` block, which may fail and not actually create a `followers` variable, as seen from the output where it prints `Soundcloud N/A`.